# Speeding up SQL spatial query gives spatial index error?

Tags: performance, sql-server-spatial

I am trying to split polylines by points which have a small buffer around them. Currently I have over 370,000 lines and 320,000 nodes and the query is running really slowly (I've left it for 3 days and it still hasn't completed). I have tried forcing a spatial index using `with (Index(SI_tempPD))` but I get the following error:

> "The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a spatial index hint. Reason: Could not find required binary spatial method in a condition. Try removing the index hints or removing SET FORCEPLAN."

Below is the snippet of code that I'm trying to run when I get the error:

```
BEGIN INSERT INTO TempLines ( [linenum] ,[ogr_geometry] ) 
SELECT lines.[linenum] ,lines.[ogr_geometry].STDifference(points.[ogr_geometry].STBuffer(0.005)) 
AS ogr_geometry FROM dbo.TemplineData AS lines with(Index(SI_tempPD)) INNER JOIN dbo.[TemplineNodes]
 AS points ON lines.[ogr_geometry].STIntersection(points.[ogr_geometry]).STDistance(points.[ogr_geometry]) < 1 
WHERE (lines.[linenum] <> points.[linenum]) END
```

Is there anyway i can speed up the query?

I also have a clustered primary key.  The execution plan shows that a filter takes up 36% of the cost and the insert takes up 64%

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (SQL server Management studio 10.50.1600.1)

Comment: You also asked this on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340208/sql-spatial-stintersection-spatial-index) -- in general, I believe cross-posting on multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You must follow the rules. If your query does not hit every point in Microsoft's list, the spatial index will not be used by the query.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx

One thing you are doing wrong: You must include in your WHERE clause a test that either excludes distances calculations that return null or has blah.STDistance(blah) < somenumber. It must be the first condition in the where clause. Putting it in the JOIN ON clause won't work.